# Where can I find a list of logics with their corresponding calculus and computation phenomena?

Tags: lambda-calculus, comparison, calculus-of-constructions, pi-calculus

I was watching [some lectures](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer12/videos/Pfenning1_0.mp4) by Prof. Pfenning on Proof Theory. Between 5:30 and 15:00, he gave a list for some different kinds of judgments along with their calculus and computation phenomena that they can represent or model. I am looking for a more comprehensive list. I would like to compare and know the advantages and disadvantages of choosing some kind of logic/calculus to represent some kind of a computational phenomenon. Which field is focusing more on such comparisons and where to start?

For example, linear lambda calculus vs pi calculus for concurrent programming. Note that I am not interested in this particular example but just to get my question across. What other mathematical logics/calculi do we have and for what type of computations?

Comment: No, I am not going to stare at this 37' video.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have specific the moment when this was mentioned in the video. Although, I think the question is already clear without the examples in the video.

Comment: Crystal clear...

Comment: @YvesDaoust Your attitude is too... which is more important than what you know ;)